# Sympy - split polynomial into two parts, positive and negative

Tags: python, sympy

I have a large polynomial in Sympy, and I need to split it into two polynomials. Where in the first are terms(monomials) with a positive sign, and in the second are all terms(monomials) with a negative sign. How to do it with good performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression can be treated like a sum of terms. Each term has an explicit or implicit coefficient that can be extracted with `.as_coeff_Mul()`. Sifting these terms based on the coefficient sign will give you the two groups you are interested in:

```
>>> from sympy import sift, Add
>>> ispos = lambda x: x.as_coeff_Mul()[0].is_positive
>>> p = -x*y**2/3 + 4*x*y + 3*x - y
>>> pos, neg = sift(Add.make_args(p), ispos, binary=True)
>>> pos
[3*x, 4*x*y]
```

To reconstruct the pieces, add them together:

```
>>> ppos, pneg = map(Add, (pos, neg))
>>> assert ppos == 3*x + 4*x*y
```

Comment: Could you add a little explanation about how this works for those unfamiliar with `sympy` methods (such as myself)? This was actually flagged as low-quality, but looks like a great Answer!